# How to add a horizontal rule in bootstrap?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms, form-helpers

I'm trying to add a horizontal rule in-between my divs.

Here is my code.

```
 Div("Name", css_class='col-sm-12'),
 Div("Address", css_class='col-sm-6'),
 Div("Favorite_Movie", css_class='col-sm-6'),
<hr> <-- Horizontal rule would go here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a [**`HTML`** object [readthedocs]](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#universal-layout-objects):

```
from crispy_forms.layout import Div, HTML

# …

Div('Name', css_class='col-sm-12'),
Div('Address', css_class='col-sm-6'),
Div('Favorite_Movie', css_class='col-sm-6'),
HTML('<hr>')
```

Comment: Hey thanks Willem, I tried that in bootstrap yesterday unfortunately it refuses to appear. I've even tried applying inline styles to make sure it's not just a visual thing. My alternative was to create a JS function that would accomplish the same thing & hope it worked.

Comment: @Bullsfan2333: does it render a `<hr>` tag in the HTML (page source)?